# How can I restore iPhone from iTunes Backup BUT keep iCloud Notes?

Tags: iphone, restore, notes.app

I lost my old iphone SE (gen 1) and most recent backup was 6 months ago (iTunes, no iCloud backup). I want to restore to a new iPhone SE (gen 2020) with the older iTunes backup BUT keep or somehow download all of my recent iCloud Notes (I do backup Notes and Contacts to iCloud). I do see in iCloud Account Advanced settings that I can restore to an iCloud Contact version, but how do this with notes? BTW, I'm using Windoz 2010 not a Mac.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

When you have restored the phone from the older iTunes Backup, it should automatically start downloading the newer notes and contacts from your iCloud account (requires internet connectivity ofcourse).